# jQuery animate navbar height on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, navbar

I've created a small function that decreases values of elements such as padding (for menu items) and height (logo) so that the navbar will decrease in height on page scroll.

What I've currently written so far is the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var scroll      = $(this).scrollTop();
    var navLink     = $('.navbar-nav > li > a');
    var navbar      = $('.navbar');
    var social      = $('.social');
    var language    = $('.navbar-right li span');
    var navImage    = $('.navbar-brand img');

    var heightDefault   = '75px';
    var paddingDefault  = '27px';
    var heightNew       = '50px';
    var paddingNew      = '15px';       

    if (scroll > 200) {

        navLink.stop().animate({
            paddingTop: paddingNew,
            paddingBottom: paddingNew
        });
        navbar.stop().animate({
            height: heightNew
        });
        social.stop().animate({
            paddingTop: paddingNew,
            paddingBottom: paddingNew
        });
        language.stop().animate({
            lineHeight: heightNew
        });
        navImage.stop().animate({
            height: heightNew
        });     

    }

});
```

For a little optimization, I've defined values and elements as variables, however as you can see, I'm running 5 separate animation functions. In addition to this, I also have 5 separate animation functions to revert the values back to default when scrolling back up.

This is most likely not best approach for this as it also includes `.stop()`.

For better optimization, would I be better off wrapping all element variables within an array and then running an `.each()` loop with 1 `animation()` inside?

Or would there be a more efficient approach? If so, would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqe2xbfq/2/) showing a more simplified version of what I'm doing for a live preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a better optimization on this, you might want to reduce the number of times those animations are started & stopped (using the `scroll` event handler will result in a lot of calls to your code).

I suggest implementing something similar to [the underscore.js throttle() function](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

Also, moving your jQuery selectors outside of the `scroll` event handler should help in improving performance.

Lastly, if it's possible in your use case, you should consider dropping the jQuery `animate()` function completely & use CSS based animations instead.

Comment: Thankyou for your input. I will experiment with the event handlers and I've also moved the selector variables outside the scroll function. Unfortunately this site must be IE8 compatible, so CSS3 transitions (as much as I would love to use them instead), are out of the question

Answer (score 0):

I'd use CSS transitions, you get less and better separated code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {            
    $(window).scroll(function() {  
        var scroll   = $(this).scrollTop();
        var nav   = $('.nav');
          
        if (scroll > 200) {
            nav.addClass('second-state');
                   
        } else {    
           nav.removeClass('second-state');
            
        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
.navbar {
    height: 75px;
}
.nav {
    background: #333;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    transition: height .35s;
}
.nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav li a {
    padding: 20px 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: padding .35s;
}

.nav.second-state{
    height: 50px;
}

.nav.second-state li a{
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;    
}

.long {
     height: 1000px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="long">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">ITEM 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this site must be IE8 compatible, thus CSS3 transitions are out of the question and I do not want to use a jQuery script for animations